What does "walk down the road" mean?
What do people mean by I was walking down the street
And does it have the same meaning as I was walking on the street

What do you think I was walking on the street means? See this usage chart showing how uncommon on is compared to down in this context.

Does this answer your question? Walking up/down a level road/street. Note that up the street is less common than down the street, but even that is more common than walking on the street. Also note that up / down don't necessarily imply the route isn't "level, flat".

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/334885/we-have-been-down-this-street-already-or-we-have-been-to-this-street-alread/334887#334887

@FumbleFingers
Does running up / Running down have the same meaning too?

Yes - run, race, stroll, stride, wander, drive, cycle... can all be used with down / up [a road, street, lane...] or with down / up to [some destination; house, shop, town...]

"Walking on the street" is not common.  If it means anything, it gives the place that you were walking.  You can say "I was walking on the grass" or "I was walking on the pavement".  There is one place implied here.

Mother: {to her child}  Don't walk on the road, a car could come around the corner at any time! Walk on the pavement.

If you mean "I was going from one place to another place then "on" is the wrong preposition to use.  You could use "along".  "I was walking along the street" means you were going from one place to another place by following the street.
But idiomatically we often use "down" or "up" the street.  The choice of "up" or "down" is subtle, and often both are possible. So "I was walking down the street" means going from place A to place B by following the street, where "B" is lower than "A" in some physical or metaphorical way.
